# I test webOS app with Ripple and get "PalmServiceBridge is not defined when "

Tags: webos, ripple

I test app with `Ripple` for `webOS`, I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: PalmServiceBridge is not defined
```

[image]

Is this a `Ripple` bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it's a bug with Ripple.  If it's going to emulate webOS devices it'll need to provide a shim for PalmServiceBridge.  I'm not very familiar with Ripple so I'm not positive how it's supposed to do its magic.

Comment: Can you please provide me link to guid, which help me with debug web apps for webOS?

Comment: Sorry for really long delay, didn't see this question!  Here are some links that might help: http://beckism.com/2011/04/remote-debug-webos/   https://developer.palm.com/content/api/dev-guide/mojo/basics-tools.html#tools-to-test-and-debug-webos-applications